# IP Address Truncated in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert the IP address in mysql, but the error message states that the IP is being truncated. The column is an unsigned int(10) in MYSQL 5.5.

Error: Data truncated for column 'initial_ip' at row 1

PHP5

```
//get the IP address
if ( isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) )    {
    $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . ' ';
    } else if ( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) )    {
    $ip=$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] . ' ';
    } else if ( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]) )    {
    $ip=$_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] . ' ';
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I believe it is simply stating that the space after the number is being truncated to convert the ip into a number.

Comment: Are you using `INET_ATOI()` MySQL function while inserting it? Otherwise MySQL thinks you're trying to insert text, not a number (and will only insert the part before first dot)

Answer (score 6):

You have to [convert the IP to an integer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton), or save it as string.

BTW: What is that space for that you add to the IP?

Comment: With "save it as string", I meant to convert the database field to varchar

Comment: I know, but why waste that much space?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store something like:

```
  127.0.0.1
```

as an integer.. this looks obviously wrong? Change int(10) into varchar(15) and it should work.

Comment: I'd suggest using more than 15 chars for varchar(), regarding to IPv6 addresses being truncated otherwise (although no very widely spread ATM)

Comment: It will work as long as you don't want to select a range of IPs or apply bitmasks to them.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP column in your database needs to be of type VARCHAR.